# Smooth Scolling in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

Hello I am working on my website with multiple pages and I want to do smooth scrolling on a certain page but I don't want to use the html tag because it will only be for this specific page and not the whole website here is my code.

```
{% if section.settings.display_product_detail_description == false and section.settings.display_product_reviews == false and section.settings.display_shipping_returns == false %}
{% assign tab5_active = true %}
{% endif %}

<div class="scroll-to-table">      
  <li class = "tab-title">
    <a href="#product_attributes_table" class="tab-links {% if tab5_active %} active {% endif %}">
    Specs
    </a>
  </li>
  </div>
```

This is the code for the HTML

```
div.scroll-to-table{
scroll-behavior: smooth;}
```

And here is the code for the CSS

At the moment all that the page is doing is a jump and not a smooth scroll. I've tried using ID instead of Class, .scroll-to-table instead of div.scroll-to-table, and changing the element in which I call the CSS from but no luck

Comment: `scroll-behavior: smooth` will work only on elements that have a scrollable content so on the window itself or other elements for which the `overflow` will result in scrollable content. `At the moment all that the page is doing is a jump` that’s because only scrolling that happens within `div.scroll-to-table` would have smooth scrolling.

Comment: What is the reason why you don’t want to apply smooth scrolling for all scrolls that happen in the window?

Answer (score -1):

We can add `scroll-behaviour: smooth` to particular page by using javascript IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). This will add the smooth behaviour to the only page that runs this script.

```
<script>
  (function () {
    document.documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = smooth;
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just add a class to the page and forego javascript?

Comment: Yes, we can do that as well. But user is using some template engine and header part probably be a reusable component.

Comment: Error: index.html:388 Uncaught ReferenceError: smooth is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>